# Any workaround for Chrome M40 redirect bug for service workers?

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker

We have images that redirect from our media server to a CDN that I'm trying to exclude from my service worker logic to work around the bug in Chrome 40. In Canary the same worker is able to work just fine. I thought there was an `event.default()` to fall back to the standard behavior but I don't see that in Chrome's implementation, and reading the spec it seems like the current recommendation is to just use `fetch(event.request)`.

So the problem I have is do I have to wait until 99% of all of our users move to Chrome 41+ in order to use service workers in this scenario, or is there some sort of way I can opt out for certain requests?

The core of my logic is below:

```
worker.addEventListener('install', function(event){
    event.waitUntil(getDefaultCache().then(function(cache){
        return cache.addAll(precacheUrls);
    }));
});

worker.addEventListener('fetch', function(event){
    event.respondWith(getDefaultCache().then(function(cache){
        return cache.match(event.request).then(function(response){
            if (!response){
                return fetch(event.request.clone()).then(function(response){
                    if (cacheablePatterns.some(function(pattern){
                        return pattern.test(event.request.url);
                    })) {
                        cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
                    }

                    return response;
                });
            }

            return response;
        });
    }));
});
```

Comment: Can you point me to URL of the bug ? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you're inside a `event.respondWith()` you do need to issue a response or you'll incur a Network Error. You're correct that `event.default()` isn't currently implemented.

A general solution is to not enter the `event.respondWith()` if you can determine synchronously that you don't want to handle the event. A basic example is something like:

```
function fetchHandler(event) {
  if (event.request.url.indexOf('abc') >= 0) {
    event.respondWith(abcResponseLogic);
  } else if (event.request.url.indexOf('def') >= 0) {
    event.respondWith(defResponseLogic);
  }
}
self.addEventListener('fetch', fetchHandler);
```

If `event.respondWith()` isn't called, then this `fetch` handler is a no-op, and any additional registered `fetch` handlers get a shot at the request. Multiple `fetch` handlers are called in the order in which they're added via `addEventListener`, one at a time, until the first one calls `event.respondWith()`.
If no fetch handlers call `event.respondWith()`, then the user agent makes the request exactly as it normally would if there were no service worker involvement.

The one tricky thing to take into account is that the determination as to whether to call `event.respondWith()` needs to be done synchronously inside each `fetch` handler. Anything that relies on asynchronous promise resolution can't be used to determine whether or not to call `event.respondWith()`. If you attempt to do something asynchronous and then call `event.respondWith()`, you'll end up with a race condition, and likely will see errors in the service worker console about how you can't respond to an event that was already handled.

Comment: There's a work in progress sample showing off this interplay at https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/pull/70